# How to SELECT multiple key/value pairs where the key is constant?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, querying

I have two tables, which I'll call `foo` and `bar`. Each table has a primary key, `foo_id` and `bar_id`, respectively. Each row in `foo` can be part of a group, which is a row in `bar` - think members on a committee, each member can be on multiple committees and each committee can have multiple members. I have a joining table which can be called `foo_bar`, which has only two columns (one each for the primary key of the other two tables) and lists which foo is part of which bar:

```
| foo_id | bar_id |
| ------ | ------ |
|   test |    res |
|   test |   res2 |
| --------------- |
```

Here is my PHP (due to my webhost I am unable to use `$stmt->get_result()`):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT bar_id FROM foo_bar WHERE foo_id = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", "test");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

Right now, printing `$result` gives me "res". How do I make it so that my result is all of the bars that the `test` foo is part of?

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dfd2/1

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `fetch` only returns one row, put it in a while loop to get the other rows.  See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php for more intformation.

Comment: @dstudeba Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding parameters for each call of $stmt-fetch();

call $stmt->fetch() again (before $stmt->close()) and $result will be "res2"

You can do this in a loop and put all of $result in an array.

Alternatively, you can do

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

$rows will then be all the result rows from the query as associative arrays.  You can then map this to an array

```
function getBarID($row) {
  return $row["bar_id"];
}

$bar_ids = array_map("getBarID",$rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mysqli` something like this :

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);  

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT bar_id FROM foo_bar WHERE foo_id = 'test'");

  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $results[] = $row;
            }
```

the `$results` will have all the bar ids with foo id equal to "test".